# Spring mvc <error-page> not working

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, error-handling, http-status-code-404, custom-error-pages

I've been searching and trying all different ways to map my customized 404 page, but nothing is working so far. The following is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     version="2.5">
  <display-name>Spring3 MVC Application</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-web</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
      org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
      <init-param>
          <param-name>throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound</param-name>
          <param-value>true</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-web</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
      <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/WEB-INF/views/404.jsp</location>
    </error-page>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-web-servlet.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>
      org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>

</web-app>
```

I've tried either just putting up error-page tag or setting up IfNoHandlerFound exception. Nothing seems to be working. Please let me know if any more code or information is needed. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Verify the real location of your page: `<location>/WEB-INF/views/404.jsp</location>`